# Unable to access classes via WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I have two projects in the same solution, a service and a consumer app.  In the service I have many classes that can be instantiated by the consumer app but some classes are not accessible.  There's no difference apart from name. All classes are all Public so they should all be seen.  Is there any buffering problems or anything else that could cause the problem to behave like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consumer does not get access to Server classes when you use WCF or any other Web Services/Removing technology. Proxy classes are created instead. Think about them as set of Interfaces that are able to call method over app boundaries. You can instantiate proxy classes but when you call method proxy class will go to Service and call corresponding method of class hosted by service.

You need to use Class Library and move move your shared classes there (and deploy dll with Service and Consumer) if both parties use them.

**Update (thanks razlebe):**
Business logic should not be shared in DLLs. It should be hosted by server. But it will make sense to share supporting classes (for example class that do data formatting) to avoid code duplication.

Comment: True - though make sure you think carefully about your design, and consider which functionality is best exposed via the web service interface and which by sharing common code in a DLL.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the classes that "are not accessible" were created after the last generation of the proxy (classes of the service, client-side). Check if REgenerating the proxy helps.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean REgenerating?

Comment: You could try to delete your Service Reference completely, and then add it again.

Answer (score 2):

When you update service class and change interface by:

- Adding a method (Your case)
- Removing a method
- Changing signature

Your consumer needs to learn about the change. You have to **update service reference** (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx) to rebuild proxy.

How to update it?

Check here to see how: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx)
But one image is better than thousand words:

[image: Visual image of updating a service reference]

Comment: I did that, update response service reference but no good.  It doesn't allow me to access certain, not all classes.

Comment: In service reference look for Reference.cs file (You need to open advanced properties or go to windows explorer). This is the class with the proxy code. Check for your new methods to see if they are there.

Comment: Nope, there's no ResponseBusinessInterruptionCover class in there, there is a a ResponsePremises class which has the same signature as the one I can't see.  Both are public, both have a standard constructor and a tailored construction.

Comment: It should be working. When it doesn't work is the moment you start to regret using WCF.
You can try as some suggested to delete reference and add it again... but probably is going to happen the same (anyway is worth try)

Another thing I would try is changing the name of your class and new method in case something is hiding these names...
Good luck!